# possible bug noticed in pandas excel function

Tags: excel, pandas

Here is the case:

First dataframe:
`product = pd.DataFrame()`

Intend to read in sheet_name=4, indeed the first sheet was read in:

`product = pd.read_excel(excelfile, nrows=1, header=None, usecols=[1], sheet_name=4)`

Check the element for this sheet:

```
product.loc[0,1]
u'CD Long-Term WAMP'
```

Check the memory address of this dataframe:

```
hex(id(product))
'0x7f326453ecd0'
```

Now create a new dataframe, confirmed it has a different memory address:

```
>>> product = pd.DataFrame()
>>> hex(id(product))
'0x7f326453ee10'
```

Read in the sheet_name=5:

```
>>> product = pd.read_excel(excelfile, nrows=1, header=None, usecols=[1], sheet_name=5)
```

Check the memory address again, no change:

```
>>> hex(id(product))
'0x7f3265ff6e10'
```

Check the element: for some reason it is showing the previous dataframe's data:

```
>>> product.loc[0,1]
u'CD Long-Term WAMP'
```

So you can see the sheet_name option in pd.read_excel is always pointing to the first sheet.

Am I missing anything here?

Thank you.

**I am using Python 2.7 from Anaconda in Linux, no same issue found in Windows.**

Comment: You write "Check the memory address again, no change:" but then give a number which *has* changed.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. yes it changed, but why the second dataframe's loc[0,1] points to the first datafrane's loc[0,1]? in fact, second product has exact the same content of first product when printed and compared.